# Adding session variable and/or cookie based on user-selected input

Tags: custom-taxonomy, wp-query, taxonomy, location-search

I am working on a classifieds website that has a custom taxonomy called 'countries'. In the main header menu I have these categories showing in a dropdown list of particular countries people can browse the site by.

How would I basically make it so when someone selects their country, it sets a session variable and or cookie with their location and from there on, every part of the site that shows a listing will use this value in a custom WP_Query to only query posts of that particular country?

So someone comes to the homepage, selects their country and then the page reloads with their chosen country for every page load thereafter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitly use PHP session variables. Follow this [blog post ("Listing 3")](http://www.kanasolution.com/2011/01/session-variable-in-wordpress/) for the best way to enable PHP sessions in WordPress. Namely, you need to use this code in your plugin or in your theme's funtions.php:

```
add_action( 'init', 'session_start', 0 );
```

After that you can use [basic session variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php) to set the country when the user selects it, and subsequently access the country that the user has selected.

Good Luck!

Comment: I know PHP quite well but wasn't sure what approach to take. Because the country dropdown uses the Wordpress menu functionality, I wrote a proxy script that an AJAX request is made to and then the proxy script returns a success or failure and I do a window.location reload. Thanks for your help, it seems to work well/

Comment: @GavinR I hope you don't mind the edit. Single functions can be attached to hooks the same as callbacks can be directly attached to for example native php functions: `array_map( 'esc_attr', $array_to_validate );`.

Comment: @kaiser Good call!

Comment: @kaiser Thanks! Agreed - that's a simpler approach.